# Testing significance of patterns of results

Tags: statistical-significance, pre-post-comparison

I'm a total novice to statistical analysis, so please forgive me if I mischaracterize anything. I have gathered pretest and posttest data about student motivation from three groups of students: one that received normal grades over a six-week period (Group 3), one that received delayed performance-contingent grades and immediate completion-contingent grades (Group 2), and one that received no grades (Group 1). The tool that I used measures seven types of motivation, which I've coded as IMK, IMA, IMS, EMID, EMIJ, EMX, and AM. My hypothesis is that feedback in the form of narrative evaluations without immediate or salient multi-interval grades (i.e., Group 1 and Group 2) will lead to better motivational outcomes for high-school students in autonomy-supportive classrooms than forms of feedback associated with immediate and salient multi-interval grades (Group 3). "Better," in this case, means that IMK, IMA, IMS, and EMID will increase and EMIJ, EMX, and AM will decrease by the end of the six-week period for students in Group 1 and Group 2. My hypothesis for Group 3 is two-tailed; I think both grades and autonomy support will have an effect, but I don't want to make any predictions about what that effect will look like - my only prediction is that the motivational outcome will be worse.

I ran a bunch of paired *t*-tests to check the significance of the difference between pretest and posttest scores for each measured variable. Here's what I came up with:

[image: Summary of Mean Differences]

Now, at a glance, you can see that the results seem to support my hypothesis. In Group 1 (Withheld), for instance, there was an increase in each of the things that I thought would increase, and there was a decrease in each of the things that I thought would decrease. It doesn't seem intuitively likely that this specific *pattern* happened randomly, even if the changes for each individual variable didn't pass the significance threshold. What sort of test could I do (ideally in R) to prove this?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Wasn't that my hypothesis, though? I predicted that the specific combination of IMK, IMA, IMS, and EMID would increase and that the specific combination of EMIJ, EMX, and AM would decrease by the end of the six-week period for students in Group 1 and Group 2 - I just don't know how to test the significance of the extent to which these combinations changed. The reason for these combinations is that they're conceptually related: IMK+IMS+IMA+EMID = autonomous motivation, EMIJ+EMX+AM = controlled / impersonal motivaton.

Comment: My apologies; I misunderstood.